# typedef for Map in dart

Tags: typescript, dart, types, structural-typing, nominal-typing

In TypeScript, I have a type definition for an object like below with generic:

```
type foo<A> = {
  val: A, 
  fns: Array<((a: A) => void)>
}
```

Now, I want to have the same structure with dart `Map` with `typedef`.

What is the syntax for this?

Comment: It might be good to describe **what** you are actually doing in typescript. Just as last time, I have no idea what the TypeScript does. I might be able to help with Dart, but you leave me no real wiggle room here. You don't have an actual question, you have a language-to-language translation task.

Comment: Dart does not support `struct` declarations. Of the similar constructs, only classes and hash maps are available. But it's not the same.

Comment: @nvoigt I think I made myself clear on what I'm trying to do, and actually, an answer told me what I'm trying to do is impossible because of the limitation of nominative type system of Dart. This is surely "language-to-language translation", but I don't understand what's wrong with specifying a solid example of "what I'm actually doing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Dart.
From Wikipedia:
A `structural type system` (or `property-based type system`) is a major class of type systems in which type compatibility and equivalence are determined by the type's actual structure or definition and not by other characteristics such as its name or place of declaration. Structural systems are used to determine if types are equivalent and whether a type is a subtype of another.

In computer science, a type system is a `nominal` or `nominative type system` (or `name-based type system`) if compatibility and equivalence of data types is determined by explicit declarations and/or the name of the types. Nominal systems are used to determine if types are equivalent, as well as if a type is a subtype of another.

Typescript based on the structural type system. So, this code is possible.
Dart based on  the name-based type system. So, this code is impossible.

This type alias does not refers to the existing type. It uses an anonymous type to specify type equivalence across its structure. Thus, the given Dart code cannot be compiled due to the impossibility of identifying the type.

```js
type foo<A> = {
  val: A, 
  f: Array<((a: A) => void)>
}
```

P.S.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the relevance.  You're talking about `class Foo {}` being distinct from `class Bar {}` even though they have the same implementation, but this question is asking about a `typedef` (a type *alias*, which does not introduce a new type) of a `Map`.

Comment: @jamesdlin Are you saying that in Dart you can declare a `Map` type with two properties? What happens to the other (already existing) members of the `Map` class? In Typescript, this will create a type with `just two properties`, which means that you can create a type this way with no restrictions on the property names of that type. How to make a `Map` in Dart in the same way, if one of the properties (not a key, but a new declared property) is required to be named `keys`. This name is already declared in the `Map` class.

Comment: @jamesdlin You may not have noticed that the identifiers `val` and `f` are not keys in the Map class. First of all, these are the identifiers of the declared properties of the new type, which can be used for indexed access. But first of all, these are the properties of the type, its legal (visible at compile time) members. How can Dart implement the same thing using the Map class and typedef?

Comment: Ah, right.  Sorry, I misunderstood what the OP is trying to achieve and had forgotten about JavaScript's equivalence of objects and associative arrays.

Comment: @jamesdlin Everything is fine. Truth is born in a dispute.

Comment: @mezoni Thanks, now I understand Dart is based on a nominative type system. Probably, this is from Java, which I don't appreciate much, and impossible on this is disappointing to me.

Answer (score 1):

Is that it you are looking for?

```
typedef MyType<T> = Map<String, T>;

void main() {
  final MyType<int> foo = {'a' : 1};
  print(foo['a']);
}
```

Comment: No, the code does not specify enough the type of the data structure. But thanks.